# Why Run-as-Administrator in an administrator user?

Tags: windows-7, administrator, runas

As you see below I have two user account on my computer, and both of them have in  administrator group.

[image]

I want to run this below program :

[image]

When I log in with Abraham and double click on **ELEnveloperGui** it can't find my dongle that is connected to the computer :

[image]

But when I right-click on it and select Run as administrator it find my dongle !!!

[image]

**Note: I have Windows-7 x64 professional**

**Q : What is the difference between `Abraham` and `Administrator`?**

---

**Update :**
I gave the program Full Permission, but problem still remain!

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure the "Administrator" does things, being aware as to what he is doing!

Comment: O.o Are you sure?!

Comment: @TheGoodUser-Sp "Run As Admin" context menu invokes the hidden built-in `Administrator` account. This hidden built-in account is the REAL Administrator account.[More details](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/507-built-administrator-account-enable-disable.html)

Comment: I think the history of "Run As Administrator" dates back to windows VISTA and the implementation of UAC warnings. In most cases the warnings were so often that users just turned off the warnings.  Part of the solution was to make most things run without administrative privileges even for an administrative user.  If the user wants however they can elevate the programs privileges by giving it administrative privileges.

Comment: @Ĭsααctիεβöss I have already Activated the built-in Administrator. but I think there is no difference between `Abraham` and `Administrator`. because as you see above, both have administrator privilege!

Comment: @Tyson would you please take a look at **Update** section in my question.

Comment: 1)  Ĭsααc tիε βöss isn't correct 2) "Run as Admistrator" purpose is to esclate the process to the Aministrator permission something that is specfically done by hand for for security reasons.  As for "What is the difference between Abraham and Administrator" **there is no difference.**

Comment: @TheGoodUser-Sp the permission you are talking about is related to file access (as in, being able to read, write or execute the file). But the discussion is about the admin "privilege", which can be gained only by "Running the program as" administrator.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is how to do this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx

Comment: The program in question really should have a manifest file to automatically esclate the permission which is provided upon the installation of the program thus having that human element.  Also what Tyson suggest is bacically the manifest file, its slightly different, but it is indeed what you want.

Comment: @TheGoodUser-Sp - while you logged into built-in Administrator account and there will be no "Run as admin" item in context menu for executable files.

Comment: @Ĭsααctիεβöss I have `Run as administrator` item even in built-in administrator account! but the program find dongle normally and I don't need to run it as administrator again in built-in administrator

Comment: Yes. You are Right. That's why I previously said that built-in admin is the Real admin. So normally it finds the dongle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft did add some restrictions even to the administrator users.
There is something called UAC (User Account Control) settings that make more restrictions to both normal users and administrators; to make sure you are not going to damage your OS by mistake, and prevent viruses from doing so.
The built-in Administrator account bypass these restrictions, that's why Microsoft disabled it.
So, if you enabled that user and used it, then you know what you are doing.

So, you can simply right click on the exe file and click "Run as Administrator", to force UAC to give you the extra needed permissions.
Or, turn off the UAC.
GO to Control Panel => User Accounts => Change User Account Control Settings.

**Upgate:**
Just to clarify some points:
When you right click on an exe file and click "Run as administrator" you are not using the built-in administrator account, you are just escalating the permissions needed by the exe file.

There is something called "**Admin Approval Mode**" in the UAC settings (can't be managed from GUI) and its disabled for the built-in administrator.
So, The built-in Administrator account runs all applications with full administrative privilege.
Check this to verify: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd834795.aspx

Just like in Linux, when you use the **root** user, you don't need to use **sudo**
And so in Windows, when you use the build-in Administrator account, you don't need to click "**Run as administrator**"

Comment: There is no difference between the built-in Administrator account's permission an account you assign to the Administrator user group.  Turning off UAC isn't a real solution thats like telling somebody to disable `sudo` on a Linux/Unix environment

Comment: I know that turn off UAC is like disable sudo and running with full root access. But, when you use the root account do you need to use sudo? No, because they are not the same!

Comment: You really should consider trying to cleanup your answer.